# How to deserialize a JSON to generic objects and get the appropriate type based on the data structure in the JSON?

Tags: c#, json, generics, json.net, json-deserialization

I want to get the generic data object returned by these JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "playlist": {
      "id": "37682",
      "title": "my_playlist",
      "count": 12,
      "duration": 9705,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But I can also get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "album": {
      "id": "372",
      "cover": ""
      "title": "Longing",
      "duration": 7705,
      "count": 12,
      "artist": "the artist"
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

My generic class that supposed to get the `data` object returned by the server:

```
    public class GenericResponse<T> : IGenericResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public T Data { get; set; }

        object IResponse.Data => Data;
    }
```

One of the object I want to deserialize to from `GenericResponse<T>`:

```
    [JsonObject("playlist")]
    public class PlaylistObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title;

        [JsonProperty("duration")]
        public int Duration;

        [JsonProperty("count")]
        public int Count;
    }
```

The request and deserialization:

```
GenericResponse result = await myEndpoint
                    .WithOAuthBearerToken(myBearer)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync(content)
                    .ReceiveJson<GenericResponse<T>>();
```

The data sent by the server is there but the `result` variable is always null when I deserialize it as `GenericResponse<T>` where `T` is either a `PlaylistObject` or an `AlbumObject`

Comment: Are you saying you don't know ahead of time if you're going to get a playlist or an album response? That seems very peculiar.

Comment: @DavidG I know which object Im supposed to get in the `data`, I want to have a generic method which return the wanted object `T` inside the `data` object. So I dont have to implement multiple strong typed methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class stucture isn't quite correct, you are missing a wrapper class around the playlist object, something that has a `playlist` property. For example:

```
public class PlaylistWrapper
{
    public PlaylistObject Playlist { get; set; }
}
```

Now you should be able to deserialise directly into `GenericResponse<PlaylistWrapper>`